# Re-routing takes around 10 seconds to plot the next path Mapbox

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox-ios, reroute

I'm working on Navigation iOS application and I'm using Mapbox for route and navigation.
Everything with Mapbox looks fine except the rerouting functionality. According to the official Mapbox documentation for iOS, re-routing get trigger when we travel 50 meter in the opposite direction. We did field testing to check this functionality and we noticed that it take around 10 to 15 seconds to draw a next route/path. 10 to 15 seconds are too much time for the drivers. we are testing when there was no traffic congestion on my route. Also when driver took 4-5 times opposite direction then route is not plotted.

I was using the default value for rerouting. Please let me know if I need to do any customisation here.

Thank you